# How to capitalize every other letter in a string efficiently in java?

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a problem in code hunt level 6.02 which asks me to capitalize every other letter in a String. I have tried doing it with toCharArray + StringBuilder in for loops. It works, but it's not good enough. I still can't get the perfect score for the problem. I'm running out of ideas. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is my first post on stack overflow. So if I miss anything or ask question in a wrong way. Pls feel free to point it out for me. Thx.

s is the input string

Attempt 1:

```
    char [] words = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i +=2){
        words[i] = Character.toUpperCase(words[i]);
    }
    return new String(words);
```

Attempt 2:

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i +=2){
        result.replace(i, i + 1, result.substring(i,i + 1).toUpperCase());
    }
    return result.toString();
```

Input: "iaiaa"

Expected output: "IaIaA"

Comment: Post the code that you have. The inherent complexity of this problem is O(n/2), which should be the complexity of your solution given that its implemented correctly.

Comment: @DavidJones Thanks for your prompt reply. I'm only getting 1 out 3. So, I'm thinking probably there exist a lgn solution or some solution faster than O(n/2), but I can't see how.

Comment: You have looped through half the characters in the words twice. The best solution can't be faster than O(n/2); that is the inherent complexity of the problem. Your solution isn't O(n/2), though because you look through half the words, twice, so your solution is O(n/2 + n/2)

Comment: @DavidJones Sorry, for making it confusing. Those are two separate attempts.

Comment: there is something weird going wrong. You HAVE to go through every 2nd character in order to capitalize them. Therefore, the efficiency cannot get any better than O(n/2), which is what you have above...

Comment: "Attempt 1" should work and should be about the fastest you can do.

Comment: The only to be much faster would be to cheat and assume ASCII alphabetics only and AND off the 0x20 bit in every other char.

Comment: @HotLicks Good point. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: One could also test the character to see if it's in the ASCII range, escaping to the `toUpperCase` call only if not.

Answer (score 0):

In both of your attempts, you're going through the characters 2 1/2 times.

Taking your second attempt;

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(s);
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i +=2){
    result.replace(i, i + 1, result.substring(i,i + 1).toUpperCase());
}
return result.toString();
```

The first line copies all the characters, and your last line copies all the characters.  Your for loop goes through half the characters, for a total of 2 1/2 sets of characters.

I don't know if this is faster, but here's my attempt.

```
String r = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        r += s.substring(i, i + 1).toUpperCase();
    } else {
        r += s.substring(i, i + 1);
    }
}
return r;
```

I realize that this looks like a lot of intermediate Strings are created, but string concatenation has improved since Java 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient this really is, but this does the trick for capitalizing the first letter and every other letter after.

```
    String sentence = "i want to manipulate this string";
    char[] array = new char[] {};

    array = sentence.toCharArray(); //put the sentence into a character array

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
        if (array[i] == ' ') { //if the character is blank, move to the next index
            i++;
        }
        array[i] = Character.toUpperCase(array[i]); //capitalize

    }

    sentence = new String(array); //revert array back to String
    System.out.println(sentence); //display
```